# Determine if graphic card is HDMI CEC capable

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, kodi

I have a EVGA GeForce 8400 GS 512 MB graphic card installed on a Windows 7 system that is used primarily as a media center using XBMC. The PC is connected to a Sony LCD using HDMI and works fine (both audio and video through HDMI)

Now, I wanted to know if there is anyway to find out if my EVGA GeForce 8400 GS is HDMI CEC compatible so I can use my TV's remote or a Universal Remote to control both the LCD and XBMC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would bet good money the card is not CEC capable. Very little PC equipment is.

Assuming your television is capable (and Sony used to limit theirs to Sony equipment only!), you'd want an HDMI-CEC to USB bridge. Like this: http://rainshadowtech.com/HdmiCecUsb.html

Again: Sony equipment (last I knew) only communicated to other Sony equipment via CEC.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid of this but didn't want to invest in more equipment. Is there any tool that can test if my graphic card is CEC compatible? I can't seem to find such tool

Comment: I'm not aware of any such thing short of plugging it into a known CEC set and trying it. I can tell you I'd put it at about 99.99% that it doesn't. Here's a quote for you: "While almost all HTPC oriented GPU cards have HDMI outputs, none of them have CEC functionality." http://www.anandtech.com/show/5463/pulseeight-usb-cec-adapter-review

Comment: Thanks. I guess another way to do this get a cheap IR Dongle and use a universal remote.

Comment: We have a Sony TV here working fine with the pulseeight adapter.

Comment: A possible alternative would be a remote control app for the phone (Yatse or Kore), which would connect to the HTPC over WiFi.